# t-sql pivot tables with multiple columns and data types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to make a pivot table that pivots multiple columns of different data types, and I'm getting a bit confused.

I currently have a table with one row for every student in every year of high school. Each row contains a lot of information about the student's performance that year: GPA, credits accumulated, courses taken in English and math, and grades received in those classes. Some of these columns are numeric and some are strings. I want to create a table with one line per student, which has a column for GPA year 1, GPA year 2, and GPA year 3, credits year 1, credits year 2, and credits year three, and so on for all of the columns in the original table.

I'm sorry if this is confusing. I would love to give you sample data to explain what I mean, but I can't figure out how to upload a file or format a table.

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the PIVOT query you attempted, and what was wrong with the results?

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot multiple columns but it gets pretty ugly pretty quickly. You have to alias the pivot column for as many pivots as will be performed since the column can't be reused for a subsequent pivot. A good naming convention helps. Finally, you'll have to aggregate the results by wrapping the whole thing in a group by.

```
with somedata ([StudentID], [Year], [GPA], [Credits], [NumMathCourses])
AS (
    SELECT 100, 2013, 3.6, 15, 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 100, 2014, 3.7, 12, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 100, 2015, 3.9, 18, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 999, 2012, 2.5, 9, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 999, 2013, 2.9, 12, 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 999, 2014, 1.8, 18, 0
)

SELECT StudentID
    ,MAX([2012gpa]) AS [GPA 2012]
    ,MAX([2013gpa]) AS [GPA 2013]
    ,MAX([2014gpa]) AS [GPA 2014]
    ,MAX([2015gpa]) AS [GPA 2015]
    ,MAX([2012cre]) AS [Credits 2012]
    ,MAX([2013cre]) AS [Credits 2013]
    ,MAX([2014cre]) AS [Credits 2014]
    ,MAX([2015cre]) AS [Credits 2015]
    ,MAX([2012nmc]) AS [Num Math Courses 2012]
    ,MAX([2013nmc]) AS [Num Math Courses 2013]
    ,MAX([2014nmc]) AS [Num Math Courses 2014]
    ,MAX([2015nmc]) AS [Num Math Courses 2015]

FROM (
    SELECT StudentID
        ,CONCAT([Year], 'gpa') AS Year_GPA
        ,CONCAT([Year], 'cre') AS Year_Credits
        ,CONCAT([Year], 'nmc') AS Year_NumMathCourses
        ,GPA
        ,Credits
        ,NumMathCourses
    FROM somedata
) [data]

PIVOT (
    MAX(GPA) FOR Year_GPA IN (
        [2012gpa], [2013gpa], [2014gpa], [2015gpa]
    )
) [pivot_gpa]

PIVOT (
    MAX(Credits) FOR Year_Credits IN (
        [2012cre], [2013cre], [2014cre], [2015cre]
    )
) [pivot_Credits]

PIVOT (
    MAX(NumMathCourses) FOR Year_NumMathCourses IN (
        [2012nmc], [2013nmc], [2014nmc], [2015nmc]
    )
) [pivot_NumMathCourses]

GROUP BY StudentID
```